# How to call API Ninjas API with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I am trying to use an API from https://api-ninjas.com/api/geocoding/. Their site provides the following starter code for how to call an API, but when I try it, the browser console just tells me that `$` is not defined.

Is `$.ajax` a stand-in for something I need to create?

Here is the starter code they provide:

```
var city = 'london'
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/geocoding?city=' + city,
    headers: { 'X-Api-Key': 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR) {
        console.error('Error: ', jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

I have tried writing `document.ajax`, but that returned the error that it was not a function. I have also tried deleting `$.ajax` and putting `fetch` in its place

Comment: `$.ajax` is a [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) method. You need to use the jQuery library to use it. Getting jQuery just for this functionality isn't worth it, and instead, it would be better for you to change your code so that it uses something like `fetch()`. Note that both `$.ajax` and `fetch` are different methods, so you need to call them in different ways. Just substituting `$.ajax` with `fetch` won't be enough. You can refer to [`fetch`s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) on how to use it to translate your code.

Comment: All you need is `const response = await fetch('https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/geocoding?city=' + city, { headers: { 'X-API-Key': 'put key here' } }); const data = await response.json()`.

Comment: @CherryDT It’s safer to utilize [`URLSearchParams`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) than to construct the URL parameters manually. `const url = new URL("https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/geocoding"); url.searchParams.set("city", city); const response = await fetch(url, { headers: { "X-API-Key": "put key here" } });` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve with the following code:

```
let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'x-api-key': 'myKey' }
  }
  
  let url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/geocoding?city=denver'
  
  
  fetch(url,options)
        .then(res => res.json()) // parse response as JSON
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`error ${err}`)
        });
```